# jQuery validation to accept natural number from asp.net textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net

This is my jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#txtLoadCode').keydown(function (key) {

    if ($(this).val().substring(0, 1) == '0') {
      $(this).val('');
      return false;
    } else {
      var keycode = (key.which) ? key.which : key.keyCode;
      var code = document.getElementById('<%=txtLoadCode.ClientID%>').value;
      if ((!(keycode == 8 || keycode == 46)) && (keycode < 48 || keycode > 57)) {
        return false;
      } else {
        //Condition to check textbox contains ten numbers or not 
        if (code.length < 5 || keycode == 8) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

This helps me to accept a 5 digit number. But when I enter only 0, it still accepts that. I want to avoid that.

Please help

Comment: try on keyup event.....

Comment: glad it helped..posted as an answer...upvote and mark as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using keydown event ...try on [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event